# nomethod error in ActiveJob

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job, rails-activejob

I am getting the following error after running `bundle exec rake jobs:work`

> FAILED (0 prior attempts) with NoMethodError: undefined method `post_it' for # Class:0x00000003375e80>

```
class PostCreationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(user_id, string, url)
    Message.post_it(user_id, string, url)
  end
end

class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

  def post_it(id, string, url)
    scraper = ForumScraper.new
    scraper.tpt_login(id)
    scraper.make_post(string, url) 
  end      
end

class MessagesController < ApplicationController

   def create
     @message = Message.new(message_params)
     @message.save
     PostCreationJob.perform_later(@message.user_id, @message.string, @message.url)
     redirect_to :back
     flash[:info] = "Posts are being processed."
   end
end
```

I am using Rails 4.2.5

```
application.rb
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Workspace
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `post_it` method is defined as an instance method, but you're calling it as a class method when you call `Message.post_it`, and so the method is not found on the class and raises the no method exception. If you define `post_it` as `def self.post_it` it will be accessible from the class as a class method.